# AssertionError while working on django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this error, i don't know how to fix it

AssertionError: Expected view ListingView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

```
class ListingView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
    serializer_class = ListingDetailSerializer
    look_field = 'slug'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListingsView.as_view()),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view()),
    path('<slug>/', ListingView.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `look_field` should be changed into `lookup_field`.

```
class ListingView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
    serializer_class = ListingDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```